# Появление лишних кнопок в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу программу для хранения паролей. При удалении последняя строка с кнопками дублируется, но удаляемая всё же пропадает.
Например,
"test1" удаляю это кнопку
"test2"
"test3"
происходит:
"test2"
"test3"
"test3"
Помогите разобраться.

```
def delete(a):
    sqlite_connection = sl.connect('passwords.db')
    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
    sql_delete_query = f"""DELETE from pass where id = {a}"""
    cursor.execute(sql_delete_query)
    sqlite_connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
 
    
def interface():
    i = 0
    data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM PASS")
    for row in data:
        pas1 = tk.Button(master=window,text=row[1], width=40, height=2, command  = lambda row=row : pc.copy(row[2]))
        pas1.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=5,sticky="wens")
        pas2 = tk.Button(master=window,text='Удалить', command= lambda row=row : delete(row[0]), width=8, height=2)
        pas2.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky="wens")
        i+=1
    window.after(1000, interface)
```

Comment: У вас постоянно каждую секунду создаются новые кнопки поверх существующих. grid не удаляет то что было раньше в этой же ячейке, а просто размещает поверх.

Comment: Ну и при удалении строки в базе у вас интерфейс не очищается, просто поверх создаются новые строки в количестве на одну меньше, в итоге старые строки внизу остаются.